How is this sentence divided exactly? を自宅寄りに
こは320号線の、目黒川を自宅寄りに越えた場所。
The character is explaining where he is  and says this
However what does 自宅寄りに越えた mean exactly? I think 目黒川を越えた場所。 is "beyond 目黒川" but what does how does 自宅寄りに fit into the sentence?

"自宅寄りに越えた" provides additional clarification about the direction. To fully understand this, let's first look at the core of the sentence:
こは320号線の、目黒川を越えた場所。
In this case, "こは320号線" likely refers to a specific road, and "目黒川を越えた場所" means "a location beyond the Meguro River." So, the sentence describes the character following the 320号線 road and crossing the Meguro River.
Now, without the phrase "自宅寄りに," the statement would leave some ambiguity about which direction he moved in. In other words, there are two possible locations he is in right now in the following picture (which is A or B):

To clarify where he is, he adds the phrase "自宅寄りに." The phrase means "closer to home." So he is likely driving his car on the left side of the road in the picture (which is closer to the home). Since cars are required to keep to the left in Japan, now it is clear that he is in the location A.
